# Push notification not working after Parse Server migration to AWS

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, amazon-ec2, push-notification

I have migrated parse server to AWS as per following link;

https://parse.com/migration

For push notification I am using AWS SNS , But I am unable to do push notification.

What can be the issue.

Comment: I have the same issue. Were you able to solve this?